# Simple conditional in react hook return

Tags: reactjs

I'm just starting with react and hooks and I terribly fail writing conditionals in the dom related return. How can I do this? The chevron should change depending on the toggle.

```
const Description = () => {
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
    const toggleTrueFalse = () => setToggled(!isToggled);
    return (
        <div>
            {if isToggled == true }{
            <ChevronRight className="arrow" size="20"/>
            } else{
            <ChevronDown className="arrow" size="20"/>
            }
        </div>

       );
    };
export default Description;
```

Comment: Why don't you follow basic Getting Started tutorial ? It's probably in the very first sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (
        <div>
            {isToggled ? <ChevronRight className="arrow" size="20"/> :  <ChevronDown 
             className="arrow" size="20"/>}

        </div>

       );
```

In return you cannot use if conditions. if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction. You got to use {} inorder to make a conditional decision. Hope this helps!